# How do I get this highlight effect on the background of this print ad?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background

I can't for the life of me find out what's the name of the effect on this print ad's background is (like how it sort of has a light shone on its center thus highlighting the object in the center), ergo I can't properly find it anywhere online. I'm trying to replicate it for a project of my own and any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Vignette

The name is **Vignette**, there's a Photoshop Filter to make it and several tutorials in internet, just search for *Photoshop vignette*.

Menu Filter → Lens Correction → Custom → Vignette

[image: Vignette]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!